# mysqlclient is not installing in python3.5 centos 7

Tags: python-3.5, centos7

mysqlclient is not installing in centos 7 and I attached the image where errors are shown so that you take idea from that. Your help is very appreciable for me.

[image]

Edit1 : @Jose
I tried your steps but at the very first step I get the following error:
Error downloading packages:

mysql-community-devel-5.6.36-2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory

mysql-community-libs-5.6.36-2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory

mysql-community-common-5.6.36-2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Please tell me why?

Comment: which guide are you using to install `mysqlclient` for Python3? I installed it recently in a few servers and the [steps](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) that I followed were: 1) `sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel` 2) `pip install mysqlclient`. Would that work for you?

Comment: Hi @JoséAntonioHaroPeralta When I try the first step I get the following error which is added in the edit question

Comment: It would not work for me @JoséAntonioHaroPeralta

Comment: I suspect there is either a problem with your repository (mirror) or your connection.

Comment: @AnitaAren thank you for your response! Can you install `strace`, run the installation with the following command: `sudo strace -o lotsalogs -ff -e trace=file yum -y install mysql-devel`, and copy the trace in your question? That will shed a lot more light on the problem

Comment: @JoséAntonioHaroPeralta When run the command given by you then I get the output like : sudo: strace: command not found

Comment: You need to install the tool first: `sudo yum install -y strace`

Comment: @JoséAntonioHaroPeralta When I run your mentioned command then at last I get the issue : Error downloading packages:
  strace-4.8-11.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: hmmmm then as @Pixelchemist says, this could be a problem with your repositories or connection. Can you run `sudo yum -y update`?

Comment: hey @JoséAntonioHaroPeralta I need your help please help me I am stuck in this. update command is not working properly

Comment: When I run the update command then I get output like : No packages marked for update

Comment: Sorry @AnitaAren I was busy before. The problem is getting more interesting :D! Her'es another thing to check: what happens if you run `sudo yum clean all` and then the `update`?

Comment: Still I am getting :  No packages marked for update

Comment: and if you try to install strace now, does it still fail? (`sudo yum install -y strace`)

Comment: yes still it fails and it can't download packages

Comment: where are you now @JoséAntonioHaroPeralta

Comment: In the above attached image, why packages are not downloaded. Do you have any idea on that

Comment: @JoséAntonioHaroPeralta have you traced my issue ?

Comment: Hi @AnitaAren sorry I couldn't come back to this. I've come across similar problems before, but not exactly this one, so I'll write shortly an answer with a few debugging steps we can take to find and fix the issue. Give me just one hour or so as I need to take of a few things right now

Comment: @JoséAntonioHaroPeralta no problem but please guide me because I don't know why it is happening with centos linux.

Comment: I posted an answer with some detailed steps @AnitaAren, please let me know if it works or not!

Answer (score 0):

ok, let's check possible issues step by step. The problem could be related to connectivity issues, broken packages, a broken rpm repository, or a problem with the mirrors used to download packages. Here are the things to look for:

1. So first thing we need to check is whether the internet connection is working fine. I'm not convinced this is the real issue, since based your comments it seems you were actually able to other packages, but you never know. Try pinging the DNS server for Google (`ping 8.8.8.8`) or curling the google website (`curl www.google.com`). If those things work, move on to the next step, otherwise we need to troubleshoot network service configuration.

If the internet connection is working fine, we need to investigate broken packages:

2. Run the following commands to clear up your `yum cache`:  `sudo yum clean all`, `sudo yum clean headers`, and `sudo yum-complete-transaction`, then try to install your package again. If still doesn't work, move on to the next step.
3. Can `yum` tell us about problem with certain packages? Run `package-cleanup --problems`. If it shows problems, please update your question with the report. Otherwise move on the the next step.
4. It's possible that some installation you made in the past made things go wrong. Do `yum history` and see if you can spot the step where everything went wrong, and use the ID to remove that step by running `sudo yum history undo <ID>`. Try installing your package now. If that doesn't work, move on to the next step.
5. Try reinstalling all packages: `sudo yum reinstall \*`. If that works, try to install your package now, otherwise paste the error in your question.

If all of your packages are fine, we need to investigate issues with `rpm`.

6. Try rebuilding your `rpm` database: `sudo rpm --rebuilddb` and then try to install again your package.

Please let me know if none of this works, and I'll update the answer.